# Sticky Items have weird positions when rotating

Tags: html, css

I made three parent Elements with a sticky Element in it. The problem is since I added rotate the text is placed wrong vertically and horizontally. For example, the elements are displayed outside the parent element and the shorter the text is the further to the left it is. Here is the code and some pictures (Press full page in snippet):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  height: 1000px;
}

.parent:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.parent:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px -1px silver;
  border-radius: 2px;
  
}
```

```html
<!-- First Parent -->

<div class="parent">

<div class="sticky">
  I'm Sticky Number One and i'm long
</div>

</div>

<!-- Second Parent -->

<div class="parent">

<div class="sticky">
  I'm Sticky Number Two
</div>

</div>

<!-- Third Parent -->

<div class="parent">

<div class="sticky">
  I'm Sticky 3
</div>

</div>
```

---

## Here are some images:

### Without rotating ✅:

[image: Without rotating]

### With rotating ❌:

[image: With rotating]

### Different alignment when text is longer/shorter ❌:

[image: alignment]

How can i fix this problem?

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: It's actually correct but just rotated. Here https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkQxm.png and here https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH6Kf.png . It's aligned in the center (horizontally) and the centered

Comment: You can use `transform-origin` to set where it rotates around, but what is the desired output?

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 yeah, i already know that. But how can i fix this problem?

Comment: @DBS I would like to have each element stay in its own parent element and all be in the same line horizontally.

Comment: sticky elements are taken outside of the normal flow, so they won't always display nicely inside their divs.

Comment: @DBS i tried using `transform-origin` with the property `left` and it looked pretty okay when adding a `left:` for example `30px`. But the top and the bottom is still not okay :(

Comment: @Kokodoko If you remove the `transform` then everything works perfectly, as I understood it

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want the final result to look like - maybe show us a picture, because I don't understand what 'all be in the same line horizontally' means (I could understand 'vertically').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `writing-mode` here

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  height: 1000px;
}

.parent:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.parent:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* added */
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: scale(-1);
  /**/
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px -1px silver;
  border-radius: 2px;
  
}
```

```html
<!-- First Parent -->

<div class="parent">

<div class="sticky">
  I'm Sticky Number One and i'm long
</div>

</div>

<!-- Second Parent -->

<div class="parent">

<div class="sticky">
  I'm Sticky Number Two
</div>

</div>

<!-- Third Parent -->

<div class="parent">

<div class="sticky">
  I'm Sticky 3
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: writing-mode + scale transform is a beautiful solution. I was tired of translates causing all kinds of side effects. This way, not only does the `top` value behave as expected, but also margins etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach for what I think you are trying to achieve:

- Add a translate to your transform to position it before the rotation. This is offsetting the element to the left, so when we rotate it around it's right edge, it rotates into lining up with the left of the window:

`transform: translate(-100%, 0) rotate(-90deg);`

- Set the translate origin to the top right, so we only need to adjust the X position in the above translation:

`transform-origin: top right;`

- To avoid overflow (Since `overflow: hidden` doesn't play well with sticky element) add a clip path to the `.parent` styles to achieve the same thing:

`clip-path: inset(0);`

Working example (It's significantly clearer what's happing if you view in fullscreen):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  height: 1000px;
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

.parent:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.parent:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px -1px silver;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!-- First Parent -->
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sticky">
    I'm Sticky Number One and i'm long
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Second Parent -->
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sticky">
    I'm Sticky Number Two
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Third Parent -->
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sticky">
    I'm Sticky 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi DBS! It works fine but when the sticky Element is at the end of the parent div then it‘s not staying in. But thank you so much for your effort